# Python+gtk fullscreen window cover (or toggle) another fullscreen application

Tags: python, gtk

Anyway to make a python GTK window cover or remove from fullscreen another window that is already on fullscreen mode?

My scenario is that I have a app in fullscreen mode (firefox) and when I call window.fullscreen() the window dont cover the firefox window, and remains in second plane.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your window manager. Which one are you using?

Comment: tested on KDE4 and another machine with metacity

Answer (score 0):

Using [gtk.gdk.Window.set_keep_above](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkwindow.html#method-gdkwindow--set-keep-above) will tell the window manager to raise your window above other windows and keep it on top, unless other windows also have keep-above set.  Some users won't like that behavior because it can make it difficult to get to or raise other windows.  An alternative is to send messages to the window manager telling it to raise your window.  I think

```
import os
...
os.system('wmctrl -a mygtkwindow')
```

will tell the window manager to raise the window whose title contains "mygtkwindow", and give it focus.

Some programs related to window manager control:  [dcop [1]](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dcop), [[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCOP), [devilspie](http://www.burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie), [wmctrl [1]](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/),
[[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wmctrl),
[[3]](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/hack-and-automate-your-desktop-wmctrl), and [xautomation](http://hoopajoo.net/projects/xautomation.html).